# ios app: How to efficiently use an existing database

Tags: ios, database

I have a single table database which is stored as an MSAccess database. It served us greatly as a desktop app for a long time, but I want to convert it to an ios app.
The table contains several hundred recordings, a key, and 20 properties. It serves us as a reference "book", and therefore some of the properties are short text, some are just words, and some are long texts containing multiple lines with indentations. As a database, it works for us flawlessly.

The question is - if I am going to build an app, what is the most efficient way of reusing this existing database and still remain the original text format?
I would like to include a search by keyword, and it should then go to a new view controller showing all the properties, as a list, something like this:

https://www.sketchappsources.com/resources/source-image/dictionary-app.png

It should be read-only, and the user could use it offline.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a table database, you could utilize the SQLite library in iOS and transfer the row data into your app.

[Here's a quick SQLite tutorial for Swift](https://www.simplifiedios.net/swift-sqlite-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Realm](https://realm.io/), which is a database for mobile platforms.  If you're just using the static data, Realm has [an import pipeline for .csv files](https://realm.io/blog/announcing-realm-cocoa-converter/) which you could export your access database to and just ship it after you've read it once.  The repo for the importer is [here](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa-converter).